# Object to store attributes of a book

Tags: java, object-oriented

I tested this code made by me in my past exam. The statement of the problem was: Write a program that allows the user to write the name of a book (string), the id (int), the price (float) and 'save' the information in a class of name Book.

It turns out I made a mistake in this line:`price=s.nextDouble();` it should be 
`price=s.nextFloat();`. My question is: Is it really bad my mistake like to mark my whole exercise as  wrong just because one little mistake :)?

```
  import java.lang.*;
  import java.util.*;


class Book{
private String name;
private float price;
private int id; 
Book(){} 
Book(String name,int id,float price){
this.name=name;
 this.id=id;
this.price=price;
 }
void setName(String nam){
 name=nam;
 }
 void setId(int ide){
 id=ide;
 }
 void setPrice(float pri){
 price=pri;
 }
 }

 class one{
 public static void main(String[] args){
 Book x=new Book(); String name=null; int id=0; float price=0;
 Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Write the name of the book");
  name=s.nextLine();
   x.setName(name);
  System.out.println("Write the id");
 id=s.nextInt();
 x.setId(id);
  System.out.println("Write the price");
  //price=s.nextDouble(); 
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- my original solution
  price=s.nextFloat(); 
  x.setPrice(price); 
  }}
```

Comment: In what way does this question contain broken code? Sure, the actual question asked is not answerable, because that depends on the examiner, but the code easily reviewable, and that would help the poster much more than answering the original question.

Comment: @RoToRa The posted code had a compilation error, due to the mistake referenced in the text. I fixed it now, but ideally OP should have done it.

Comment: The part that  is fixed changing has exactly to do with OP's question, whose answer would largely be opinion-based. OP, marking it wrong may seem harsh but it serves to parallel the error you would get had you attempted to compile this. Uncompilable code is just as good as no code at all, to a computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, it is not easy to guess what exactly wrong for examiner.

Here are my ideas for improvements.

- The most important mistake is using float/double for financial values. See details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).
- You have some dead code, for example, the constructor with 3 arguments is not used.
- Preferable way is to have immutable objects. Such objects have [some benefits](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140528113353-16837833-6-benefits-of-programming-with-immutable-objects-in-java) and knowledge of this fact may increase you exam results.
- Missed output result for end user when all needed attributes were entered. May be not required by exam task but nice to have, will be as additional bonus  :)
- Naming issue: like `id=ide;` in setters. For this case better as `this.id = id;`.
- Declare local variables exactly in place of the first usage.
- Not formatted code in your original post. This is a minor style issue.

Here is my version:

```
class Book {
    private final String name;
    private final int id;
    private final BigDecimal price;

    Book(String name, int id, BigDecimal price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book{" + "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                ", id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Write the name of the book:");
        final String bookTitle = s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Write the id:");
        final int bookId = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Write the price:");
        final BigDecimal bookPrice = s.nextBigDecimal();

        final Book book = new Book(bookTitle, bookId, bookPrice);
        System.out.println("Entered book is " + book);
    }
}
```